# How do I create a dict, with csv column contents as keys, and occurrence count as value?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a `csv` file with the following columns:

```
Item Name, Item Type, Manufacturer Name
```

I need to write a function that creates a dictionary, where the keys are the phrase in the `Item Type` column and the value, is the occurrence count of the phrase, then I need to print that dictionary.

As far as I can see, it adds the `Item Type` as the key, but runs into a problem storing the associated value.

Here is the csv contents:

```
Item Name, Item Type, Manufacturer Name
Elektra Clone,Fuzzstortion,ollieMAX! Pedals
Sputnik II,Fuzz,Spaceman Pedals
Pumpkin Pi,Fuzz,Green Carrot Pedals
Carcosa,Fuzz,DOD
Big Muff Pi (Black Russian),Fuzz,Electro-Harmonix
Octopuss,Passive Octave Up,Bigfoot Engineering
Small Stone,Phaser,Electro-Harmonix
Grand Orbiter,Phaser,Earthquaker Devices
Hummingbird,Tremolo,Earthquaker Devices
Echosystem,Digital Delay,Empress Effects
Freeze,Sound Retainer,Electro-Harmonix
Ditto,Looper,TC Electronic
Stamme[n],Glitch Delay,Drolo
```

Here is my code:

```
def countItemTypes(fileName):
    #create an empty dictionary as we need to store key/value pairs
    itemDic = {}
    # where fileName is the name of the csv file
    #first we must open the csv file and read it
    import csv
    with open(fileName, "r") as itemFile:
    #we are using itemFile as the handle
        csvReader = csv.reader(itemFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        #skip the header because we don't need to do anything with it
        next(csvReader)
        #now that we have skipped the header we need to iterate through the rows
        for row in csvReader:
            #troubleshooting diagnostic, for loop:
            #print(row)
            #now we need to take the second column entry of the csv and assign that as the key
            #and the total number of its instances as the value to that key
            #quite frankly I have no idea how to do that.
            if itemDic[row[1]] not in itemDic:
                itemDic[row[1]] = 1
            else:
                itemDic[row[1]] += 1
        #print the new dictionary
        print (itemDic)
```

It runs into `KeyError: 'Fuzzstortion'` when it hits:

```
if itemDic[row[1]] not in itemDic:
    itemDic[row[1]] = 1
else:
    itemDic[row[1]] += 1
```

Comment: There is a better solution than using `if-else` to check for a `key` and iterate `value`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `if` condition is that you actually want to check for this

```py
# Check row[1] not in the dictionary
if row[1] not in itemDic:
    itemDic[row[1]] = 1
else:
    itemDic[row[1]] += 1
```

Comment: It works! You are incredible and amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

- `defaultdict` if from the `collections` module and is a subclass of `dict`.  It's similar to a `dict`, the exception being, a `defaultdict` will set a default value for a new `key`. `defaultdict` removes the need to first check if a `key` exists and sets a value.
- Replace `itemDic = {}` with `itemDic = defaultdict(int)`

  - `itemDic = Counter()` works too, as per [Raulillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11824299/raulillo)
  - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- Replace `if-else` section with `itemDic[row[1]] += 1`
- Code implemented below

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter  # pick which one you want to use
import csv


def countItemTypes(fileName: str) -> defaultdict:
    """
    Parse a csv file and return a dict with the word count
    of the second column, Item Type
    fileName: Name of csv file to parse
    """
    # create empty defauldict
    itemDic = defaultdict(int)  # or you can use itemDic = Counter()
    # open fileName
    with open(fileName, "r") as itemFile:
    #we are using itemFile as the handle
        csvReader = csv.reader(itemFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        #skip the header
        next(csvReader)
        # iterate through the rows
        for row in csvReader:
            # assign word from second column as a key and count occurrences
            itemDic[row[1]] += 1
        #return the new dictionary
        return itemDic
```

- now there is no `if-else`, so the code has been simplified.
- The function also includes the following:

  - `"""description of the function"""`: docstrings [Documenting Python Code: A Complete Guide](https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/)
  - [Type annotations](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#annotations)

#### Usage:

```py
word_count = countItemTypes('test.csv')
print(word_count)

>>>
defaultdict(int,
            {'Fuzzstortion': 1,
             'Fuzz': 4,
             'Passive Octave Up': 1,
             'Phaser': 2,
             'Tremolo': 1,
             'Digital Delay': 1,
             'Sound Retainer': 1,
             'Looper': 1,
             'Glitch Delay': 1})
```

Comment: Maybe [Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can improve your answer further.

Comment: @Raulillo So, similar to `defaultdict`, but specific to counts, so it doesn't need to be initialized with `default_factory`.  I like that it's so specific.  Thanks for the recommendation..

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question in your **`if` statement**:

```
itemDic[row[1]] not in itemDic
```

`itemDic` stores pairs type-repetitions.

- What you are asking:

  *Is the **repetition of the type** in row[1] not present in the dictionary?*
- What you are trying to ask:

  *Is the **type** in row[1] not present in the dictionary?*

  `row[1] not in itemDic`

Just as a note, try to put all imports at the start of the file, it's more clear and readable.